# Azure AD B2C - Using ADFS as an Identity Provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The client we are attempting to integrate with has ADFS as their IDP. The customer is trying to use Azure AD B2C as their IDP.

The error is that Azure AD B2C tries to connect to their SAML endpoint directly which is not open to the public, so it fails.

Is there a way to upload their Federation.xml file into Azure AD B2C so that it doesn't try to connect to the URL?

Answer (score 5):

You can embed a SAML IDP's metadata in the custom policy directly by setting the the value of the `PartnerEntity` item within the ClaimProvider's Metadata to have a `<![CDATA` element.

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>mysamlidp</Domain>
  <DisplayName>My SAML IdP</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="MySamlIdP">
      <DisplayName>My SAML IdP</DisplayName>
      <Description></Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="RequestsSigned">false</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity"><![CDATA[
<!-- REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR METADATA XML -->
<EntityDescriptor Id="..."><!-- ... --></EntityDescriptor>
<!-- REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR METADATA XML -->
                    ]]></Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
      <!-- ... etc ... -->
```